# Regex check if a character only occurs at the end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to match a string which is only valid if *all characters after the first occurrence of the target character, are also the the target character.*

To better understand the structure, for example our target character is `.`. The string is divided into two parts. The matching string has the following structure:

1. substring **without** the target character
2. substring **with no other characters than** the target character

Let's examine some examples:

```
""
// true - 1: "" doesn't contain target - 2: "" doesn't contain not target

"2"
// true - 1: "2" doesn't contain target - 2: "" doesn't contain not target

"."
// true - 1: "" doesn't contain target - 2: "." doesn't contain not target (only target)

"2.."
// true - 1: "2" doesn't contain target - 2: ".." doesn't contain not target (only target)

"...."
// true - 1: "" doesn't contain target - 2: "...." doesn't contain not target (only target)

"..2"
// false - 1: "..2" contains target - 2: "" doesn't contain not target

"2.2"
// false - 1: "2.2" contains target - 2: "" doesn't contain not target

"2.2."
// false - 1: "2.2" contains target - 2: "." doesn't contain not target (only target)
```

I was approaching the problem first with String methods (JS) by checking index of first occurrence, then counting number of occurrences, comparing with the length of string to check if there are any other characters between the ending, which was solving the problem, but wasn't looking too nice, and I don't think it's the most efficient way to solve the issue.

It looks like this:

```
const validate = (string, targetChar) => {
  const firstTargetIndex = string.indexOf(targetChar);
  if (firstTargetIndex === -1) return true; //no chance of not target following a target

  const substringAfterFirstTarget = string.substr(firstTargetIndex);
  const numberOfTargets = substringAfterFirstTarget.split(targetChar).length - 1;
  return substringAfterFirstTarget.length === numberOfTargets;
}
```

Then I was researching regex methods to solve the problem, but I only found methods for checking occurrence, number of occurrence, if string ends with (even n times, but ignoring if there are occurrences between other characters), but couldn't figure a method to match the above test.

Comment: please make an attempt before asking

Comment: You want to know my search history or my failed attempts? How would the results I've found not solving the issue help anyone?

Comment: And you may be way closer to the solution than you expect

Comment: is this javascript or some other language? do you need to use regex alone or can you use other logic?

Comment: shouldn't "2.2." be true?

Comment: No, only true if it ends with. If we would loop through the string, from the end, and keep removing the last characters if it’s a dot, we should end up with a string without dots. If there’s still a dot, it doesn’t match

Comment: it looks to me like it DOES end with.  I guess you mean "...is not in it, XOR ends with it..."  OK, try: "^[^.]*\.\.*$|^[^.]$|^$"

Comment: @GergőHorváth by showing at least one thing you've tried, it helps us get a sense of what you do or do not understand about how to approach the problem.  It helps an answerer determine whether to explain everything from scratch, explain just one aspect of the solution, clear up a specific misunderstanding, or just point out a face-palm.

Comment: Is this a valid rewording? _"All characters after the first occurrence of the specified character, must also be the specified character."_

Comment: Yes, it perfectly explains the goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex `^[^.]*\.*$` should work. It can accept any none `.` character 0 or more times (`[^.]*`) and then it can be followed by any number of `.` (`\.*`)

```js
const regex = /^[^.]*\.*$/gm;
const str = ['','2','.','2..','....','..2','2.2','2.2.'];

console.log(str.map(s=>s.match(regex)?'true':'false'))

// example from comments does return false
console.log(regex.test('..2.'))
```

Comment: If you only want `true` or `false`, you might as well use `regex.test(s)`. ([And remove the `gm` flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-does-a-regexp-with-global-flag-give-wrong-results).)

Comment: ..2. returns true but should return false

Comment: @Andrew Are you sure?  I tried it and '..2.' **does** return false.

Comment: I posted my results in my answer; please check.  Maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

In English: match if it is zero or more non-dot chars followed by zero or more dot chars:

```
Mac_3.2.57$cat test.txt | egrep "^[^.]*\.*$"
2
.
2..
....

x

Mac_3.2.57$cat test.txt

2
.
2..
....
..2
2.2
2.2.

x
Mac_3.2.57$
```

PS
The previous answer did not work for me:

```
> const str = ['','2','.','2..','....','..2','2.2','2.2.'];
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'str' has already been declared
> console.log(str.map(s=>s.match(regex)?'true':'false'))
[
  'true',  'true',
  'true',  'true',
  'true',  'false',
  'false', 'false'
]
undefined
> const str = ['','2','.','2..','..2.','..2','2.2','2.2.'];
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'str' has already been declared
> console.log(str.map(s=>s.match(regex)?'true':'false'))
[
  'true',  'true',
  'true',  'true',
  'true',  'false',
  'false', 'false'
]
undefined
>
```

Comment: code only answers are discouraged, you should include some explanation on how OP is supposed to apply this answer to their code.

Comment: @Chris  OK, doing now

Comment: @Chris  done; it's a good practice--in this case, it made me realize the RE could be reduced.  thanks

Comment: Much better, thanks! The same thing goes for writing questions, 90% of the time if we put enough effort into the question we manage to resolve the issue as part of the research process

Comment: FYI:  I now just fixed a ^k issue in my post (my sol'n somehow was not showing up).

Answer (score 0):

1. Case where dot is not in string: `^[\.]*$`
2. Case where dot ends the string: `\.$`

Put them together with alternation, you get dot at end or not at all

```
(\.$)|(^[\.]*$)
```